# Is there a shorthand notation for this operation?

Tags: c, math, division, shorthand

Is there no shorthand notation like `/=` for this operation in C?

```
int variable = 5;

variable = round(variable / (float)2);
```

I can't think of any.

Comment: Oh, forgot to specify. C.

Comment: Yes there is, `variable = round(variable / 2.f);` or `variable = round(variable / 2.);` :D

Comment: For positive values you can use `(variable + 1) / 2` instead of using floating point operations.

Comment: @interjay I don't follow. I assume this would work only with odd numbers, but variable doesn't necessarily have to be an odd number always.

Comment: It works with odd and even numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it really depends what you're doing. Most of the time you shouldn't be actually concerned about *shortcuts* but *readability and correctness*. In this case your code is quite readable but it is not very correct, because it code divides by a float so the result has only23-24 bits of precision, less than in an `int`; even if you use a double `2.0`, you get that 53-54 bits of precision which is less than long long int.

---

The codes below are likely not only faster but also work correctly in more cases.

If you want to work with **unsigned numbers** (or signed with non-negative values), then you can do this:

```
unsigned int variable = 5;
variable = (variable + 1) >> 1;
```

i.e. add 1 and bitshift right.

If you need to support signed and are using C99+ or C89 with properly-defined division (truncating towards zero), you can do

```
variable = (variable + (variable > 0 ? 1: -1)) / 2;
```

These work because integer division always return an integer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (int i = -5; i <= 5; i ++) {
        int variable = i;
        variable = (variable + (variable > 0 ? 1: -1)) / 2;
        printf("%3d\t%4.1f\t%3d\n", i, i/2.0, variable);
    }
}
```

will print out:

```
 -5     -2.5     -3
 -4     -2.0     -2
 -3     -1.5     -2
 -2     -1.0     -1
 -1     -0.5     -1
  0      0.0      0
  1      0.5      1
  2      1.0      1
  3      1.5      2
  4      2.0      2
  5      2.5      3
```

Comment: The number of bits in the significand of an IEEE-754 “double” is 53, not 54. And only the number of bits in the significand, 24 for “single” and 53 for “double,” is relevant when discussing the behaviors of the values. The fact one of the fields used to encode them has fewer bits is irrelevant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am talking about `round(variable / (float)2);` and the numbers are guesstimate because I am not interested in **exact** math of something that is not the correct way to do something. If you have more time then please calculate for me the result would be precise up to how many bits for `MAX_INT`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if you use the original formula for something like `INT_MAX - 64` the result is off by ~32. That is because of the precision of float. That is actually precise to 25 bits I guess...